# more than 1 annotation on map with postcode, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I have set up a map and am getting postcodes from Firebase and putting them into an array of strings called places.

When the map loads it only shows 1 annotation pin on the map even though the print function shows 3 postcodes.

Below is my code.

```
func showSightingsOnMap(location: CLLocation) {
    places = pCodes
    print("Tony: Places \(places)")
    let geocoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()


    for eachAddress in places {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(eachAddress) { (placemarks, error) in
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(placemark: (placemarks?.first)!)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(placemark)
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Have you tried to print inside your callback ? Usually hitting geocoder inside a `for`can cause issues. Try putting a print right after `geocoder.geocodeAddressString(eachAddress) { (placemarks, error) in` like `print(placemarks?.first)` and `print(error.localizedDescription)` and see whats going

Comment: I think you need do this with NSOperation, and after you get all your placemarks the put all of them in your MapView

Comment: This is what i get when i add the print statements into the geocode.......  Tony: Placemark Optional(PO1 5DS, Portsmouth, PO1 5DS, England @ <+50.80052360,-1.07232480> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+50.80052360,-1.07232480> radius 50.03', center:<+50.80052360,-1.07232480>, radius:50.03m))
Tony: nil

Comment: You have a bigger problem. geocoding methods like geocoder.geocodeAddressString are rate-limited. The docs say, among other things: "Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action." If you submit too many requests at once  then the API may drop your extra requests. See the docs on CLGeocoder. The overview at the beginning talks about the limits apps need to follow.